# Is it possible to do conditional steps in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to use MTM to test the website I develop.  The problem is that there are three different possible things that could happen after entering your username and password and clicking the login button.
1. Redirected to the register security questions page.
2. Redirected to the answer security questions page.
3. Redirected to the homepage.

I would like to set up the test case to handle these different possibilities.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need to handle the test in one test case, you could put all of the test steps for the different outcomes into the test case as multi-line test steps and just skip the test steps that didn't apply while testing.

The alternative is you could put the first part of the test into "shared steps" and create separate test cases based on the different possibilities.

More on shared steps: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286655.aspx